# You'll need me for much

Tags: riddle

You're no stranger to words...

You know the spelling rules, and so do I!

A full commitment's what I'm thinking of

You wouldn't get this from any other one

I just wanna tell you I'm feeling rejection

Gotta make you understand

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you could desert me.

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you can't desert me.

---

**(Note: you do not have to explain the below)**

And if you ask me what I am

Don't tell me you're too blind to see

This riddle has some ease.

Can you tell what I am?

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you could desert me.

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you can't desert me.

---

Hint 1:

> You might see me on your palms.

Hint 2:

> I'm a big recursive commitment.

Hint 3:

> Umm.. I don't think that is the correct answer, too. (A homophone is present in this hint)

Comment: I misread lines 7&8 and almost flipped my table..

Comment: Lines 7&8 flipped my table. I know it is also reference to a song. RICK ROLLL PEOPLE.

Comment: See the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it :

> The letter "M"

You're no stranger to words...

> Letters are used to create words

You know the spelling rules, and so do I!

> The rule about the letter "N" before the letter "M"

A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other one

> Commitment might be the word with the most "M"

I just wanna tell you I'm feeling rejection
Gotta make you understand

> No idea yet

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you could desert me.
You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you can't desert me.

> I think this about the way to write a "M". First the pencil goes up then down. At this point you could stop and that would make a "N" (lowercase). And you go up and down again to make a "M".

You might see me on your palms.

> There is a "M" in palms

I'm a big recursive commitment.

> No idea (might be about the "M" in commitment again)

Umm.. I don't think that is the correct answer, too. (A homophone is present in this hint)

> Umm = "M" homophone

Answer (score 4):

I think it is

> '

Note:

> I think that this puzzle is a kind of autobiography of **'**, who is pained by its misuse (or no use).

You're no stranger to words...

You know the spelling rules, and so do I!

> ' is quite instrumental in the spelling of words like **it's**, **I'm**, etc.

A full commitment's what I'm thinking of

> **'** wants us to use it wherever it is necessary.

You wouldn't get this from any other one

> No other punctuation sign can provide the functionality of **'**.

I just wanna tell you I'm feeling rejection

Gotta make you understand

> **'** is often wrongly used, or not used in words like **its, it's, can't, shouldn't** etc. It wants us to understand its usage, and use it correctly.

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you could desert me.

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you can't desert me.

> *Pick me up* and *let me down* refers to the wrong use of **'**. 
>  **could** does not have an **'**, so we can desert it at that point.
>  But **can't** does have an **'**, so we cannot desert it at that point.

---

On going through the puzzle today I see that you have added some hints. All the hints point to the letter

> U

You might see me on your palms.

> Of course, I can see `u` on "yo**u**r palms"

I'm a big recursive commitment.

> I think that this points to letter `w` which is pronounced, as double-u. Or may even be the recursive u in the spelling of words like vacuum, continuum, etc.

Umm.. I don't think that is the correct answer, too. (A homophone is present in this hint)

> too is a homophone of u

**Title** : You'll need me for much

> Yes! I'll need **u** for m**u**ch.

Comment: You're on the right track with using a character as the answer, but this is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> 2

You're no stranger to words...

> Too and to, homophones, are used pretty often.

You know the spelling rules, and so do I!

> '2' understands the difference between 'too', 'to', and 'two'.

A full commitment's what I'm thinking of

> Because too and to are used so often, '2' would also like to be used more often. '2' might also be feeling overshadowed by '1'.

You wouldn't get this from any other one

> '1' has less homophones than '2', and their meanings/values are different.

I just wanna tell you I'm feeling rejection

> As mentioned before, '2' might be feeling overshadowed by '1'.

Gotta make you understand

> 'He's' hurt!

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you could desert me.

> This is the first line, thus you 'could' desert '2'.

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you can't desert me.

> This is the second line, thus you can't desert '2', since you've already used him.

**Hints**

You might see me on your palms.

> I guess you could see a 2 on your palms... its kind of distorted.

I'm a big recursive commitment.

> Recursion uses the first term to build onwards, and so people often use 2 to check if their code/pattern works.

Umm.. I don't think that is the correct answer, too. (A homophone is present in this hint)

> 'Too' is the only word that is sort of out of place in this hint, and it is a homophone of two!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is:

> The letter "E"

You're no stranger to words 
You know the spelling rules, and so do I

> The letter "E" is the most frequent letter and it has a lot of associated rules

A full commitment's what I'm thinking of

> No idea

You wouldn't get this from any other one

> The letter "E" behaves different from other vowels, which are already exclusive

I just wanna tell you I'm feeling rejection

> This letter is left silent at the end of words

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you could desert me.

You're gonna pick me up. You're gonna let me down. And at this point you can't desert me.

> The letter can occur twice in a row? I didn't get this either

Also, that was a nice parody.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. However, you're getting closer to the correct answer.

Comment: Could you tell me in what way?